# python outlook 2010 error : (-2147467262, 'No such interface supported',None,None)

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting the error message below when I try the code:

```
(-2147467262, 'No such interface supported',None,None)(-2147467262, 'No such interface supported',None,None)
```

the code

```
    import win32com.client as client
    
    outlook=client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
    
    namespace=outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    
    Der=namespace.Folders['Drive']
    
    Dinbox=Der.Folders['Inbox']
    Dinbox_list=[x for x in Dinbox.items if x.Categories==""]
    for message in Dinbox_list:
        
        if "xyz" in message.CC or "xyz" in message.To :
            message.Categories="xyz"
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs trying to handle - let's say - unusual messages in your inbox or in any other folder. I got the same error when trying to read EntryID of a recalled message (which is visible in Outlook, but cannot be opened). So your code will have the same problems with the object. Solution: Put your last if-statement in a try-except-block.